# The connection was reset with client SSL verification

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I had a server with server side ssl working.

I've added :

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCaCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/MyCA.crt
```

And now I get a connection reset every time I try to load a page. There are no errors in the error.log. And no errors on Apache restart.

The client certificate is not yet installed in the client. The browser is FF 23.01. I should be getting an error that says, "This site requires a certificate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox looks to see you have have a certificate signed by the requisite CA. If you don't, it doesn't prompt you to supply one. This could probably be considered a usability bug, since you're right- it should say, "you need a certificate to access this URL" or similar.